# Why is `_wassert` wrapped in `(..,0)`?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assertion

I was wondering why the _wassert function is wrapped in `(..,0)`

```
    #define assert(expression) (void)(                                                       \
            (!!(expression)) ||                                                              \
            (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), (unsigned)(__LINE__)), 0) \
        )
```

Comment: I guess it is used to discard the result value of  `_wassert`

Comment: @BryanChen And to make it suitable as the right operand of `||`. In all likelihood the return type of `_wassert` is `void`.

Comment: I'm amazed that this question received just 1 upvote so far (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_wassert` function is called when the assertion fails.  This will:

1. Print the assertion failure.
2. Call `abort` (or `exit` or some such function to end execution).

As such it isn't going to return and is declared to be a void function (as mentioned by T.C. in the comments). (It must be declared void or the compiler will complain that it doesn't return a value).

So then when it gets used in the expression `test || _wassert(...)` the compiler will complain because that doesn't type check.  It needs two numeric types for the `||`.  So the solution is to make the right hand expression return an int (even though it will never ever return due to the `abort`), and to do that they use the comma operator.